# Background worker in selfhosted WCF Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, ipc

I am completely new to WCF and multithreading. So, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/137605/self-hosting-in-wcf/) to set up a selfhosted WCF service. After I right-clicked on the Interface "INews_Service", I clicked on "implement Interface". Then, VS creates a method named DoWork().

In the tutorial above, the DoWork() method is not needed (-> it is deleted). However, in my project, I would like to use this method to run a background worker thread/task.

In my project, the background worker is supposed to permanently load data from an external device and store it in the DataContract-class. The WCF Service, in turn, is supposed to simultaneously provide the instance of that DataContract-class to external WCF consumers.

In reference to the tutorial above, what is the best way to add a background worker method, which constantly changes the variables within an instance of the DataContract-class?

**EDIT:**

@Brian: Thank you very much! The following example shows the selfhosted service program from the tutuorial above. After I start the host, I would like to run an endless loop that constantly updates my DataContract-class. Can you make an example, how this can be done? I do not need any synchronization, such as SpinLock or Monitor?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCF_NewsService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(News_Service));
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host Open Sucessfully ...");
            while (true)
            {
                //here I want to constantly update my DataContract-class TOInews
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Actually, my problem is that I don't know how to access my DataContract-object `objtoinews`, which is defined in another file (i.e. in *NewsService*, as in the tutorial). When I run something like `objtoinews.ID = 1;`, VS complains that *objtoinews* is not defined in the current context.

```
while (true)
{
    if (host.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
    {
        throw new Exception("SynchronizationWS Service Host failed.");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        objtoinews.ID = 1;
        objtoinews.Header = "blabla";
        objtoinews.Body = "huhu";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use DoWork in a WCF solution. Basically, the console program described in that tutoral will perform DoWork() when the Host.Open() is called. In other words, Host.Open() will do what you expect DoWork() will do.

The console acts as the executable, but all the work is done asynchronously/multi-threaded in the background by WCF service.

Booz, I'm not sure why you think you need to continously update your DataContract. I don't think you can, actually, while the program's running. If you're worried about people sending different data constructs to your WS host, maybe you need to abstract the structure so that (basically) your clients can send virtually anything.

In any event, here's the code I'm use to loop and check the status of my web service:

```
while (true) {
   //broken connection case
    if (wshost.State != CommunicationState.Opened) {
        throw new Exception("Service Host failed.");
        //dump from loop and throw error
        break;  
    }

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);       //sleep 1 second 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course, you're right, it's all asynchron. However, I am still having issues with updating my DataContract-class (see edited post). It would be great if you could have a look at it. Thank you!!

Comment: I just edited my previous post. My problem is that I don't know how to access variables in my DataContract-object.

Comment: Why I want to continuously update my DataContract: I am using WCF as some kind of "Backend" Service, rather than a webservice. This Backend is supposed to continuously read data from an external device and I want to use WCF so that other applications (from different operating systems) can access those constantly changing datasets via different communication channels. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, I think I know what the issue is. You're trying to put in your functional code within "step 6" of that tutorial, but the functional code goes into step 5. That's where you read and write to variables, write crap to the database, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know, that would be an option. However, reading data from my external interface is a very time-consuming process. Therefore, I wanted to have parallelization. When I add my functional code at step 5, the WCF consumer has to wait until data is read from the external device and further transferred via WCF. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Actually, I could overcome that issue by adding an additional class, which acts as a buffer between my external device and my DataContract. However, I was hoping that there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: Boozzz ... not sure what to suggest. The problem you're trying to work around isn't something I've run into.

Comment: But you understand what I'm planning to do, right? Thanks a lot for your help!!